# How to draw circle and move in c#

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm trying to draw one circle and move it in one form in c #. I use GDI to draw, as follows.
Suppose that I have 1 class Circle

```
int postitionX, postitionY, radius, angle;
void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.DrawEllipse(Pen, postitionX, postitionY, radius, radius);
    g.FillEllipse(SolidBrush, postitionX, postitionY, radius, radius);
}
```

and in form main I init circle(postitionX=0, postitionY=10, radius=20, angle=30;)

```
private void form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     <caculation postition next>
    mycircle.Draw(e.Graphics)
}
```

But the problem is that function form_Paint run many times and make circle move out display.
Can someone give me no solution?

Comment: Paint is what triggers the painting. You should calculate the position somewhere else and there should also trigger the Paint event by Invalidating the control. DO NOT put an Invalidate in the Paint, which will create an endless loop.. - Where and when do you want to calculate the move? By a Button_Click? Or in a Timer_Tick..?

Comment: Just a side note. You are using gdi+ not gdi. The *invalidate* code calls *paint*

Comment: So suppose I draw the path of the circle go 3 points. if i use timer tick then how.
 

       `private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // Go to point 1
`   // Go to point 2`
`   // Go to point 3`
    Invalidate(); // This will force a repaint
}`
So the circle will go through point 3 then form_main start redraw.I did not want that. So, how can not you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invalidate` will cause a full repaint of your form and will invoke your `form_Paint' event handler. This will cause an endless loop. (I see now TaW was just earlier).
If you want to animate a circle on your form, you could use the following approach:

Put a `Timer` on your form, set `Interval` on 30 and `Enabled` to True. Implement the `Tick` event:

```
private int deltaX = 1;

private int deltaY = 1;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // TO DO your caculation postition, like so:
    // be sure window width/height  is much larger than 2 * radius:           
    if ((postitionX - radius) <= 0)
        deltaX = 1;
    if ((postitionX + radius) >= ClientRectangle.Width)
        deltaX = -1;
    positionX += deltaX;

    if ((postitionY - radius) <= 0)
        deltaY = 1;
    if ((postitionY + radius) >= ClientRectangle.Heigth)
        deltaY = -1;
    positionY += deltaY;
    // Now you have calculated a 'new animation frame'. 

    // Now force repaint to draw.
    Invalidate(); // This will force a repaint
}
```

Now update your form_Paint handler:

```
private void form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // caculation postition next HAS TO BE REMOVED FROM HERE
    mycircle.Draw(e.Graphics)
    // Invalidate(); HAS TO BE REMOVED FROM HERE
}
```

By playing with the valye for `timer1.Interval` in combination with your calculations of next position, you can make the animation slower or faster.

Comment: So suppose I draw the path of the circle go 3 points. if i use timer tick then how.
 

       `private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // Go to point 1
`   // Go to point 2`
`   // Go to point 3`
    Invalidate(); // This will force a repaint
}`
So the circle will go through point 3 then form_main start redraw.I did not want that. So, how can not you

Answer (score 0):

So suppose I draw the path of the circle go to 3 points. if i use timer tick then how.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Go to point 1  
// Go to point 2 
// Go to point 3
}
private void form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // caculation postition next HAS TO BE REMOVED FROM HERE
    mycircle.Draw(e.Graphics)
    // Invalidate(); HAS TO BE REMOVED FROM HERE
}
```

So the circle will go through point 3 then form_main start redraw.I did not want that. So, how can not you

Comment: I've updated the code sample. If you set radius to 12, you will see a circle moving and bouncing against the sides. I hope this will give you starting point for your own position calculations.